# Get a HTML list to dynamically alternate between two columns

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

I have an html list that I need to get split into two columns. I'm curious if I can do this purely in CSS without changing the HTML code.

For example:

I have a list like this:

- Item 1
- Item Longer 2
- Item really long 3
- Item this 4
- Item five 5
- Item 6

But I want to display the list as two columns with equal width, but without changing the HTML code.

I've tried using child selectors and inline display but I can't figure out how to get the second column to start evenly.

This is what I'm trying to achieve in CSS. That way if I keep adding to the list, it keeps alternating the content between columns, as well as always having the second column be even.

[image]

```css
li {
display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item Longer 2</li>
<li>Item really long 3</li>
<li>Item this 4</li>
<li>Item five 5</li>
<li>Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u85avecb/

Comment: If that's what you want to achieve in CSS please post the html featuring showing those terms. Or post a picture showing the terms you're currently using laid out as you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use columns like this without changing your html code :

```css
ul {
  -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item Longer 2</li>
<li>Item really long 3</li>
<li>Item this 4</li>
<li>Item five 5</li>
<li>Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow I feel stupid for not thinking of this. Worked exactly how I wanted, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try using a flexbox.

```css
ul {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
list-style: none;
max-height: 60px;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item Longer 2</li>
<li>Item really long 3</li>
<li>Item this 4</li>
<li>Item five 5</li>
<li>Item 6</li>
</ul>
```